# How to set Google Fonts .xml programmatically to TextView

Tags: android, xml, fonts, google-fonts

Since with Android Studio 3.0, you can simply integrate google fonts to your project [(See android walkthrough)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html#via-android-studio).

When you add some font, Android Studio generates you the font folder including XML file for the font (in my case amatic_sc.xml). Also Studio create a preloaded_fonts.xml in value folder.

amatic_sc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Amatic SC"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

preloaded_fonts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="preloaded_fonts" translatable="false">
        <item>@font/amatic_sc</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

When I'm include the following line static into my xml file, it works fine:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/amatic_sc"
```

But in my case I need to set the font family programmatically in my custom listAdapter. I tried following code exemples, but nothing works:

```
// Display text with default fontFamily
viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("@font/amatic_sc", Typeface.NORMAL));

// both throws java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found [../res/]font/amatic_sc.xml
viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/amatic_sc.xml"));
viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "../res/font/amatic_sc.xml"));

// both throws java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found [../res/]font/amatic_sc.xml
viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile("font/amatic_sc.xml"));
viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile("../res/font/amatic_sc.xml"));
```

In my case, I use min **SDK version 16** and I hope my code snippet is sufficient.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Matze, have you found the solution for the issue. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: currently i haven't a solution :(

Answer (score 22):

You can use the support library as to be compatible with android versions prior to 8, like this:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context,R.font.amatic_sc);
viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getFont(android.content.Context,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

save font file inside assets folder then use this snipt

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), fontPath);
v.setTypeface(font);
```

notic: font path should some thing as

> Roboto-Bold.ttf